# I am receiving an error like "physical path is not allowed ,virtual path only allowed " while exporting a excel file need to save in specific location

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code:

```
private void ExportToExcel()
{
    try
    {
        String strToday = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yy/hh:mm");
        DataTable dtBrand = (DataTable)ViewState["dtItemList"];
        if (dtBrand.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Excel" + strToday + ".xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            GridView grdBrand = new GridView();
            dtBrand.Columns["BrandName"].ColumnName = "BrandName";
            dtBrand.Columns["CloseQuantity"].ColumnName = "CloseQuantity";
            dtBrand.Columns["ClosingValue"].ColumnName = "ClosingValue";

            grdBrand.DataSource = dtBrand;
            grdBrand.DataBind();
            for (int i = 0; i < dtBrand.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                grdBrand.HeaderRow.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.FloralWhite;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < grdBrand.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                grdBrand.Rows[i].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
            }
            grdBrand.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            grdBrand.HeaderRow.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            grdBrand.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
            Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

            //string filePath = Server.MapPath("E://Excel/");
            //string fileName = "Excel_" +strToday+ ".xls";

            //// Write the rendered content to a file.
            //string renderedGridView = stringWrite.ToString();
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath + fileName, renderedGridView);
            Response.End();
        }
        if (!((dtBrand == null)))
        {
            dtBrand.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {  

    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using MapPath with a virtual path (~/.....) instead of a hardcoded (E://Excel/) path.

Comment: but i need that file to store in the client machine on a specific directory and folder.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood, which line does the error occur? Is the Server.MapPath code commented out? Why do you say "store on the clients machine" when Server.MapPath is clearly a server-side only command? The way you have it with `Response.Write` will export it to the client BUT doing that shouldn't give the error you're getting with Virtual Path's, I believe it's to do with Server.MapPath.

Comment: Yes correct, but i need to save the exported excel file to a particular directory like D: or E: or F: . Is there any possibility that i can access the client  machine to generate the folder and save the exported excel file to save in that directory location like (D:/Export/Brand/BrandReport.xls).

Comment: **No**, unless you're using ActiveX (a date technology supported by old versions of IE) you cannot create folders and files on the Clients PC. The only way to do it is get the end users to save the file in the C:\Excel manually. This is a fundamental of web programming with Client/Server setups. For security reasons you cannot use the clients file system.

Comment: Thanks jeremy sir for your prompt response.